# If universe is expanding shouldn't its 'disorderness' decrease?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, disorder

I've came across Clausius Inequality which says that entropy of an isolated system always increases (in an irreversible process).

Assuming universe to be an isolated system, a time will come when everything in this universe will come in equilibrium. During that time everywhere in space temperature and other properties will be uniform and there will be no heat exchange.

Now here lies my problem, if entropy is a measure of disorderness of a system(that I've been told by my beloved instructor), then don't you think that during that point of time when everything is in equilibrium there will be no disorder and entropy will be minimum.

But, this contradicts the Clausius Inequality which says that entropy of the universe CANNOT decrease. Moreover I feel feel that during Big Bang, entropy was maximum because of maximum chaos (temperature was high, many particles confined in a very small volume of the system, i.e the universe, looks like a chaotic situation to me).

Comment: While for a lab system, the word  "isolated" has a well definite meaning, I am afraid that statements on the universe are not so simple to justify.

Comment: Moreover, the relation between order and entropy is less simple as you think. The order connected to thermodynamic entropy actually corresponds to situations of non-uniform distribution of the intensive quantities. The uniform distribution would be the most disordered. However big care has to be used when dealing with the universe. You have to take into account that gravitating systems have a very unusual thermodynamics (just to cite one of the problems, specific heat is negative).